# Creating a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a following data set that I read in from a text file:

```
all_examples=   ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']
```

I need to create a list of dictionary as follows:

```
lst = [ 
{"A":1, "B":2, "C":4, "D":4 },
{"A":1, "B":1, "C":4, "D":5 } 
]
```

I tried using an generator function but it was hard to create a list as such.

```
attributes = 'A,B,C'
def get_examples():

    for value in examples:
        yield dict(zip(attributes, value.strip().replace(" ", "").split(',')))
```

Comment: Your desired output dictionary is not correct. Please edit your post.

Comment: Why not have a single key point to a list containing the mapped values, instead?

Comment: You can have a list that contains dictionaries. But you can't have a dictionary , that just contains lists. You need key:value pairs in a dictionary. Also your input is strictly a list of strings. So look up using `split` to turn that into a list of lists first.

Comment: I think you have []'s mixed up with {}'s. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A one liner, just for fun:

```
all_examples = ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']

map(dict, zip(*[[(s[0], int(x)) for x in s.split(',')[1:]] for s in all_examples]))
```

Produces:

```
[{'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 2, 'D': 4}, 
 {'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 1, 'D': 5}]
```

As a bonus, this will work for longer sequences too:

```
all_examples = ['A,1,1,1', 'B,2,1,2', 'C,4,4,3', 'D,4,5,6']
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 2, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 1, 'D': 5},
 {'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'D': 6}]
```

Explanation:

```
map(dict, zip(*[[(s[0], int(x)) for x in s.split(',')[1:]] for s in all_examples]))
```

- `[... for s in all_examples]` For each element in your list:
- `s.split(',')[1:]` Split it by commas, then take each element after the first
- `(...) for x in` and turn it into a list of tuples
- `s[0], int(x)` of the first letter, with that element converted to integer
- `zip(*[...])` now transpose your lists of tuples
- `map(dict, ...)` and turn each one into a dictionary!

Comment: great solution, but is there anyway to create an ordered dictionary? The result here is unordered.

Comment: Regular dictionaries in python are always unordered; if you want an ordered one just add `from collections import OrderedDict` and use that instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 3):

Also just for fun, but with a focus on understandability:

```
all_examples = ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']
ll = [ x.split(",") for x in all_examples ]
ld = list()
for col in range(1, len(ll[0])):
    ld.append({ l[0] : int(l[col]) for l in ll })
print ld
```

will print

```
[{'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 2, 'D': 4}, {'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 1, 'D': 5}]
```

Works as long as the input is csv with integers and lines are same length.

Dissection: I will use the teminology "thing" for A, B and C and "measurement" for the "columns" in the data, i.e. those values in the same "csv-column" of the inut data.

Get the string input data into a list for each line: `A,1,1` -> `["A","1","1"]`

```
ll = [ x.split(",") for x in all_examples ]
```

The result is supposed to be a list of dicts, so let's initialize one:

```
ld = list()
```

For each measurement (assuming that all lines have the same number of columns):

```
for col in range(1, len(ll[0])):
```

Take the thing `l[0]`, e.g. "A", from the line and assign the numeric value `int()`, e.g. 1,  of the measurement in the respective column `l[col]`, e.g. "1", to the thing. Then use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to combine it into the next line of the desired result. Finally `append()` the `dict` to the result list `ld`.

```
    ld.append({ l[0] : int(l[col]) for l in ll })
```

View unfoamtted. Use `print json.dumps(ld, indent=4)` for more convenient display:

```
print ld
```

Hope this helps. Find more on dict comprehensions e.g. [here](http://www.diveintopython3.net/comprehensions.html#dictionarycomprehension) (Python3 version of this great book).

Comment: can you explain a bit on this one?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a list of strings, and you'd like to have a list of paired dictionaries generated from the same key in the tuple triplets of each string.

To keep this relatively simple, I'll use a for loop instead of a complicated dictionary comprehension structure.

```
my_dictionary_list = list()
d1 = dict()
d2 = dict()
for triplet_str in all_examples:
    key, val1, val2 = triplet_str.split(',')
    d1[key] = val1
    d2[key] = val2
my_dictionary_list.append(d1)
my_dictionary_list.append(d2)

>>> my_dictionary_list
my_dictionary_list
[{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '4', 'D': '4'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '4', 'D': '5'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be "How to crate list of dictionaries?". Here's something you would like to consider.

```
>>> dict={}
>>> dict2={}
>>> new_list = []
>>> all_examples=['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']
>>> for k in all_examples:
...     ele=k.split(",")
...     dict[str(ele[0])]=ele[1]
...     dict[str(ele[0])]=ele[2]
...     new_list.append(dict)
...     new_list.append(dict2)
>>> dict
{'A': '1', 'C': '4', 'B': '2', 'D': '4'}
>>> dict2
{'A': '1', 'C': '4', 'B': '1', 'D': '5'}
```